# Чередование массива

Tags: массивы, qt, c++

Сортировать массив из 100 чисел так, чтобы было чередование отрицательных и положительных элементов массива (С++)
Если не сложно, то с комментарием строк.

Comment: А если их не поровну? То есть не 50 на 50 ?

Comment: есть 2 варианта. если вам нужна строгая очередность массива положительное, отрицательное итд то тогда надо сначала отсортироветь весь массив. а потом о очереди обменять местами `2 + 2*0 vs n - 1* (2*0)`, 2 + 2*1  vs n - (1 + 2*1), 2 + 2*2  vs n - (1 + 2*2) ...` 
если же вам просто нужна сортировка с игнорированием значения тогда сравниваете абсолютные величины чисел (берете сортировку напр. пузырьком на вики. и там где идет сравнивание элементов добавляете abs(value), - или как там у вас в С :) )

Comment: В данном случае их 50 на 50

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем, придумал 3 варианта. Работаем с обычным массивом int.

Вариант 1. Самый простой, с созданием временного массива и обратным его копированием в изначальный массив

```
void put_mem (int* vec, size_t ss) {
    int temp [ss];
    for (int i = 0, pi = 0, ni = 1; i < ss; i++) {
        if (vec[i] >=0) {temp[pi] = vec[i]; pi +=2;}
        else {temp [ni] = vec[i]; ni +=2;}
    }
    memcpy (vec, temp, sizeof(int)*ss); 
}
```

Вариант 2. С работой непосредственно в массиве наподобие пузырьковой сортировки. Ввел дополнительную вспомогательную функцию swapp для обмена значениями между членами массива. Алгоритм тупой и прямой без оптимизации.

```
static inline void swapp (int& a1, int& a2) {
    int temp = a1;
    a1 = a2;
    a2 = temp;    
}

void put_sw (int* vec, size_t ss) {
    size_t j;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ss; i++) {
        if (vec[i] < 0) {
            j = i;
            while (vec[++j] < 0);
            swapp (vec[i], vec[j]);         
        }
        i++;
        if (vec[i] >= 0) {
            j = i;
            while (vec[++j] >= 0);
            swapp (vec[i], vec[j]);         
        }           
    }
}
```

Вариант 3. Самый навороченный, с применением STL. Но будет работать только с массивами, размер которых не делится на 4.

```
 void put_stl (int* vec, size_t ss) {
    int* it = partition (vec, vec+ss, bind2nd (less<int>(), 0));
    for (int* itt = vec; it < vec+ss; it+=2, itt+=2) {swap (*itt, *it);}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

В этом коде, если отрицательных или положительных чисел больше, то они просто дописываются в конец, ну а как же еще? Не отбрасывать же их =)

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void print_r(int *mass, int size)
{
    for (unsigned i = 1; i <= size; i++)
    cout << mass[i] << ", ";
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int mass[100];
    for (unsigned i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    mass[i] = rand() % 100 - 50;
    print_r(mass, 100);
    int h_m[100];
    int s_m[100];
    int c = 0;
    int c2 = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    if (mass[i] < 0) {
        c2++;
        s_m[c2] = mass[i];
    }
    if (mass[i] > 0) {
        c++;
        h_m[c] = mass[i];
    }
    }

    cout << endl;
    print_r(h_m, c);
    cout << endl;
    print_r(s_m, c2);
    cout << endl;
    int new_mass[100];
    int min = 0;
    if (c > c2)
    min = c2;
    else
    min = c;
    for (int i = 1; i <= min; i++)
    cout << s_m[i] << " " << h_m[i] << " ";

    if (min == c)
    for (int i = min + 1; i <= c2; i++)
        cout << s_m[i] << " ";

    if (min == c2)
    for (int i = min + 1; i <= c2; i++)
        cout << h_m[i] << " ";

    system("Pause");
}
```

---

Если же отрицательных и положительных элементов поровну, то их можно просто вывести в цикле от 1 до 50 поочередно.